# PHP Exception with symfony mailer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-mailer

I'm a beginner with Symfony, and I have to put a Mailer in my web service. But I have a php exception that I don't understand.

There is my mailer function :

```
 private function sendMail(MailerInterface $mailer, $p_leTI, $mail)
          {
             $pole = $p_leTI['pole'];
             $type = $pole === 1 ? 'Logiciel' : ($pole === 2 ? 'Matériel' : 'Incident');
             $client = $p_leTI['nomCli'];
             $email = (new Email())
                 ->from(new Address('random@gmail.com', 'Support Idéation Informatique'))
                 ->to(new Address('random@gmail.com'))
                 ->bcc(new Address('random@gmail.com'))
                 ->subject("Ticket $type Site: $client")
                 ->text("Client: $client\r\nObservation: {$p_leTI['OBSERVATION']}")
                 ->html("<html lang='fr'>
                     <body>
                         <p>Demandeur: {$p_leTI['nomCli']}</p>
                         <p>Description: {$p_leTI['OBSERVATION']}</p>
                         <p>Téléphone: {$p_leTI['TEL']}</p>
                         <p>Email: {$p_leTI['EMAILCLIENT']}</p>
                     </body>
                 </html>");
             $mailer->send($email);

             $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
                 ->from(new Address('random@gmail.com', 'Support Idéation Informatique'))
                 ->bcc(new Address('random@gmail.com'))
                 ->subject("Idéation Informatique - Votre demande a bien été enregistrée (Ticket n°" . $$p_leTI['IDTICKETINCIDENT'] . ")");
             if (!empty($mail))
                 try {
                     $email->to(new Address($mail));
                 } catch (Exception $e) {
                     
                 }


             $email->htmlTemplate('emails/mail.html.twig')
                 ->context([
                     'client' => $client,
                     'idticket' => $p_leTI['IDTICKETINCIDENT'],
                     'observation' => $p_leTI['OBSERVATION']
                 ])
                 ->text("Ouverture du ticket incident n°" . $p_leTI['IDTICKETINCIDENT'] . "\r\n" . $p_leTI['OBSERVATION']);

             $mailer->send($email);
             return true;
          }
```

And there is the error in my log :

```
PHP Exception Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException: "Environment variable not found: "MAILER_DSN"."dency-injection/EnvVarProcessor.php
```

EnvVarProcessor.php is a file I never worked with so I don't understand, like I said I'm a beginner so I might have forgot something.

Thank's for you're help.

Comment: Error message is pretty clear, you have to [create an environment variable `MAILER_DSN`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#transport-setup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the parameters how your mails should be sent via an environment variable (there are plenty options but there are some common ways).

Most easy one [as documented](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#transport-setup) is to update the `.env` file with:

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://user:pass@smtp.example.com:port
```

Comment: `EnvVarProcessor.php` is just the component to set the env variables in the Symfony container based on the different options one has to set them.

Comment: Note that if you're using some real credentials, you want to write it in `.env.local` instead of `.env` so it is not committed.

Comment: URL might need to be URL encoded first if there are special characters in the password in example (like `@` becomes `%40`)